# Tabs/Windows in Chrome apps

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

It appears that chrome apps are unable to render as tabs in the browser...   I happen to like the chrome tabbing interface and it would be a shame to have to try and re-implement it in html/css/js.  Is there really no way to do tab management at the chrome application level?  Must all new windows be shell/panel level windows?

I can imagine scenarios for applications where they would want to contribute extension related features to the browser...  why are you making it more confusing for users (who now have to install an app and an extension) in order to get the full feature set?

Is there really no room for middle-ground here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome apps are separate from the browser. This is a very deliberate approach, which is unlikely to change.

For apps to be seen as apps, as opposed to websites, which are always available regardless of connectivity, they need to be seen as separate to a browser. We have found having apps launched and run outside the browser very important for users to conceptualize them as apps.

There are also security reasons to keep apps out of the browser. They have access to APIs that websites and extensions do not have access to, but to make this possible they are also individually sandboxed and have no access to the browser.

Extensions and apps can communicate via messages. It is less than ideal that a user may need to install both an app and an extension; we have been looking at some form of bundling to make this simpler.

Comment: I'd be very interested in the bundling you speak of, and perhaps some examples on the documentation about how you envision extensions and applications coordinating data.  I assume they will not have access to the same indexed db instances?

Comment: Have you given any thought to letting apps have the tab api back and only control tabbing within their own windows?   I say this because I've been hoping for some serious document management tools to spring up in the chrome echosystem and I would hope that the native tabbing that chrome does could translate to the apps as well.

Comment: That's right, at the moment extensions / apps can't share the same indexed db instances, or other sandboxed data. That is also something we're looking at (specifically for related apps but there is no reason it wouldn't apply to extensions).

Comment: There was some discussion about letting apps use the chrome tab stuff instead of reimplementing it in html/css/js, but we decided not to. Technically the work would be significant and we'd be imposing a tab look and feel on apps, which we don't want to do.

Comment: Sorry I meant to add: There are many libraries you can use which will give you a tab style interface.

Comment: Thank you very much for the responses.  Wrt your last comments about letting applications do the tabbing themselves, I have performance concerns about putting so much dom in 1 window.  As an application developer, I would love the choice of using native tabbing, in some circumstances, they would just make for a better user experience.